# Visual Studio 2008 not nesting files properly in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a VS 2008 WinForms project, and I recently added an existing form that was developed in a different VS 2008 project. All of the original forms and controls are nesting correctly, however, with the new form, it is showing the form, designer and resx files as 3 separate items.

Is there a way to force VS to nest these files properly? I've been through the settings, googled, been to MSDN, and can't seem to find information on this.

Comment: lets see what the project file looks like for that portion (.csproj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the new form is called "Form1"
 should look like this for it:

```
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: So I should just edit the project file manually? I can see that the sub files have no "DependentUpon" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the .csproj file with, say, Notepad.  The `<DependentUpon>` elements are missing.

Comment: Thanks! +rep but Voodoo was faster.