# visual studio class file turned into miscellanous file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this weird issues with my solution file, all my codes behind and class files are classified into miscellaneous files, I already tried unloading and reloading my project as suggested, I also disconnected it from tfs..I'm using VS2015, because of this my intellisense does not work..neither my peek/goto 
definition.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <ExternalProgram>
      </ExternalProgram>
      <StartExternalURL>
      </StartExternalURL>
      <StartCmdLineArguments>
      </StartCmdLineArguments>
      <StartWorkingDirectory>
      </StartWorkingDirectory>
      <EnableENC>True</EnableENC>
      <AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>True</AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>
    </WebProjectProperties>
  </FlavorProperties>
</VisualStudio>
```

that's the proj. user file

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the solution for analysis (Or part of it)? Some printscreens of whats happening and/or copy of the .csproj file?

Comment: The solution file `(.sln)` does not contain information about individual code files.  It only contains information about projects.  You would need to look at your project file `(.csproj)`.  If you have, indeed, added code files directly to your solution, intellisense and other tools would probably not work properly anyway.

Comment: would this question help you? It heppened to me a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017052/visual-studio-2008-not-nesting-files-properly-in-solution-explorer

Comment: what I meant was ..all the codes(projects) under the solution

Comment: if you look at my screenshot..all the projects/classes under that solution is all misc files..this solution is pulled from tfs. I saw in one of the bugs in visual studio preview that this issue was a bug and has been fixed. but take note..that is in preview version and I have professional version w update 3. this happens with 2 separate solution.